# I have categorical feature and i don't want to use one hot encoder as it will increase number of dimension in my datasets what option do i have now?

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree, one-hot-encoding

My model is based on Decision-Tree algorithm hence I want to avoid One hot encoder as it will increase training time. I know a technique where i know instead of taking one hot encoding, I can go with an option of probability of category with respect to my classified output.But i don't know how to apply that probability part.?

Answer (score 0):

Decision Trees can handle both numerical and categorical variables, therefore there is no need to encode your categorical variables.

Comment: Suppose you have a feature name zipcode/pincode as we know zipcode isn't number it an area pincode which is unique.

Comment: you said decision tree  can handle both numerical and categorical feature but i was getting an error . I was forced to use label encoder

Comment: hey i am newbie so if i am wrong then please correct me

Comment: This is an implementation-specific problem. What class of which package are you using for the DT model?

Comment: Suppose you have a feature name zipcode/pincode as we know zipcode isn't a number it an area pincode which is unique areawise. So in that scenario instead of considering one hot encoding, i want to take "probability" of that particular "zipcode" w.r.t to my class